# How to navigate to another page in reactjs using switch or if else statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, events, switch-statement

I am trying to perform a task where a user types in a word in the search box, and if the search box is empty or null show error, and navigate to the respective path, else show the result and navigate to the respective path.

Please see the code below i tried,

```
    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if( window.location.pathname === "/movies" && event.key === 'Enter' && searchText !== '')
    {
       history.push('/movies')
    }
    else  if( window.location.pathname === "/tvshows" && event.key === 'Enter' && searchText !== '')
    {
       history.push('/tvshows')
    }
   else if(searchText === '' && event.key === 'Enter'){
       alert ("Please enter text to search")
   }
}
const handleClick = (event) =>{
    if (searchText === '')
    {
        alert("Please enter text to search")
    }
    else if (window.location.pathname === "/movies"  && searchText !== '')
    {
        goToMovies()
    }
    else if (window.location.pathname === "/tvshows" && searchText !== '')
    {
        goTotvshows()
    }
}
```

The code on tvshow page or component

```
  const tfilterData = ((val) => {
    if (props.searchText === "" ) {
        return val
    } 
    else if (val.title?.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchText?.toLowerCase())) {
        return val
    } 
    
} );

{ tvData.length === 0 ? <NotFound notfound = "noResultText" /> : tvData.filter(tfilterData).map((tvshows) =>{
      return(
          <Card className={classes.cardMain}  key={tvshows.id}>
      <CardActionArea>
          <CardMedia className = {classes.cardImage}>
              <img style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}} 
                  src ={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${tvshows.poster_path}`} 
                  alt = "tv poster"/>
          </CardMedia>
          <CardContent className = {classes.cardContent}>
              <Tooltip title = {tvshows.name} placement="top">
              <Typography className = {classes.movieTitle}>  {tvshows.name} </Typography>
              </Tooltip>
              <Typography 
                          className = {classes.typography1} 
                          variant="body2" 
                          component = "p"
                  > {tvshows.first_air_date} 
                  </Typography>
              <Rating 
                      className = {classes.typography2} 
                      name = "ratings"
                      value =  {tvshows.vote_average/2} 
                      precision={0.5}
                      readOnly                                
              />                             
          </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions style = {{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}} >
          <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small">Watch</Button>
          <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small" >Share</Button>
          <Button className = {classes.cardButton}size = "small" onClick = {   ()=> addToWatchlist(tvshows) }> Add </Button> 
      </CardActions>                   
  </Card>
      );                    
  })}            
  </div>
```

the code on the movie page/component

```
  const filterData = ((val) => {
    if (props.searchText === "" ) {
        return val
    } 
    else if (val.title?.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchText?.toLowerCase())) {
        return val
    } 
    
} );

 <Grid
            item
            xs
            container
            direction="column"
            justifyContent="flex-start"
            alignItems="flex-start"
            style={{ backgroundColor: "black", width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
        >
            <div className={classes.filtermain}>
                <div className={classes.filterinner1}>
                    <Button className={classes.frecentlyadded}>Recently Added </Button>
                    <Button className={classes.fmostpopular}>Most Popular</Button>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.filterinner2}>
                    <Button className={classes.fyear}>Year</Button>
                    <Button className={classes.fgenre}>Genre</Button>
                    <Button className={classes.flanguage}>Language</Button>
                    <Button className={classes.fsortby}>Sort by</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
           
            <div  className ={classes.Main} > 
            { movieData.length === 0 ? <NotFound notfound = {noResultText} /> : movieData.filter(filterData).map((movie) =>{
                return(
                    <Card className={classes.cardMain}  key={movie.id}>
                <CardActionArea>
                    <CardMedia className = {classes.cardImage}>
                        <img style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}} 
                            src ={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.poster_path}`} 
                            alt = "movie poster"/>
                    </CardMedia>
                    <CardContent className = {classes.cardContent}>
                        <Tooltip title = {movie.title} placement="top">
                        <Typography className = {classes.movieTitle}>  {movie.title} </Typography>
                        </Tooltip>
                        <Typography 
                                    className = {classes.typography1} 
                                    variant="body2" 
                                    component = "p"
                            > {movie.release_date} 
                            </Typography>
                        <Rating 
                                className = {classes.typography2} 
                                name = "ratings"
                                value =  {movie.vote_average/2} 
                                precision={0.5}
                                readOnly                                
                        />                             
                    </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
                <CardActions style = {{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}} >
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small">Watch</Button>
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small" >Share</Button>
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton}size = "small" onClick = {   ()=> addToWatchlist(movie) }> Add </Button> 
                </CardActions>                   
            </Card>
                );                    
            })}            
            </div>
        </Grid>
```

The Error
[image]

any help is much appreciated. I tried this but it shows an error message and the app gets crashed.

Comment: Your code uses `=` to compare to the pathname, which is incorrect; `=` is for **assignment** of values; `==` and `===` are for comparisons.

Comment: Hi @Pointy Thanks a million for the help however I corrected the issue now am getting the below error any leads on this why? 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TvShows
C:/Users/tapesh.patel/Desktop/ReactProjects/moviehunt/src/components/Movies/TvShows.jsx:155

Comment: There are no references to a `length` property in the code you posted, so I don't know.

Comment: Hi @Pointy I have updated the code could you please help ?

Comment: Well the error means that `tvData` is `undefined`, so attempting to reference `tvData.length` cannot work.

Comment: @Pointy

But I guess I have difined it 
  const [tvData, setTvData] = useState([])

Also the error only triggers when I try to enter any word in search box else the app show no error. 

Waht might be the reason to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241263/discussion-between-tapesh-patel-and-pointy).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

So I found the answer, the error was that it had the **same naming convention for the API or object** I was using, and I found on the internet **that dom renders the first or the last value which it will get**, and if they both are same it will through such error.

Thanks